# Slick images in responsive

Tags: jquery, css, .net

In desktop mode I want to display three image in centre mode.
But in responsive I have to display only single image but it display three images in responsive:

[image]

**View**

```
<div class="slider-section2" style="overflow:hidden">
   <div class="slid-container">
       <ul class="slickImage" ng-if="loadSwiper" ng-init="previewAd.loadSwiperImages()">
           <li ng-repeat="image in ads.adDetailForPreview.MainAdsImages track by $index">
               <div class="block-cont">
                    <img ng-class="IsRegularSizeAd?'':'DoubleSizeImg'" ng-src="~/Content/Images/AdsImages/{{image.Path}}" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".slickImage").slick({
     centerMode: true,
     infinite: true,
     autoplay: false,
     centerPadding: '0px',
     slidesToShow: 1,
     arrows: true
});
```

Please any one have an solution to fix this?

Comment: Why not remove it using CSS? Use media queries to detect if you are on a phone or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breakpoints?
Like this:

```
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }
]
```